# How to verify that the recipient received a payment?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I sent a Bitcoin payment using Circle Pay. According to my Circle Pay the transaction is completed. It's been two days and the person on the other end is claiming they have not received the money. How can I check to see if he is telling the truth. From what I read, all transactions are public, correct?

Comment: Yes they are public. You should be able to send the transaction ID where you sent them funds and you can verify them.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the address of the recipient on a blockchain explorer (e.g. https://blockexplorer.com/). If the address shows your payment as confirmed, it must have arrived.

It may show, but still be marked as unconfirmed which would explain why the recipient states that they haven't received it yet.

Answer (score 1):

as Murch says, you could search a transaction on a blockchain explorer (eg. [blockexplorer.com](https://blockexplorer.com), [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info), ...).

Searching a specific transaction could be according of "transaction hash", "sender address" or "receiver address" of that transaction. It's trivial that if you search by transaction hash, with a high probability a unique result will be show to you, otherwise searching with addresses show all transactions of that address and you must find the proper one that represents your transaction.

After finding your transaction you must see it's status ("unconfirmed" or "n Confirmations") and then you could prove your assertion by presenting this link of blockchain explorer to anybody.

Answer (score 1):

1. check that the address of the recipient is right and valid
2. check transaction id from Circle Pay
3. search for the transaction by its id on http://blockchain.info
4. if the transaction is confirmed, it's included in the blockchain, otherwise it's still stuck in miners' memorypool and require higer fees

Answer (score 0):

Just lookup his public key on Blockchain.info and see if your payment is there. If it has arrived but is unconfirmed, it may be a symptom of all the trouble lately. Keep in touch with the seller and attempt to contact Circle Pat, they can probably re- send the exact same transaction ( with same ID) if it is stuck.