# Unspent bitcoin transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, blockchain.info, transaction-verification, listunspent

So about two weeks ago i sent bitcoin to a friend, and it was confirmed but in the summary it was listed unspent, he claimed not to have received. I was really confused since then, now this morning i check again and i noticed the status has changed to ‘spent’. Now i am more confused. Does that mean he has finally recieved it? ***i tried contacting blockchain support but i didnt get a response**

Comment: You need to look to your chat history and see if the address coins were sent to is the address your friend gave to you. If so, they are trying to make you send again to scam you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bitcoin sent, recipient claiming not received](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/92058/bitcoin-sent-recipient-claiming-not-received)