# Why does an X show in search bar when I paste a Bitcoin address in Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain.info

I sent some Bitcoin twice to an address (3QiGE6rfL5PiCN8werdtXTsqeG6drN4oVm) and yet they say never received the funds.

Also why does an X show up in search bar in Blockchain.com when I paste the above Bitcoin address?

Comment: Searching in any blockchain explorer including blockchain.com works for me.

Comment: Are you talking about the X on a gray disk that appears in the end of the search field? If yes, clicking that resets the search input field to empty. Try hitting `ENTER` instead, and then clicking the currency you're interested in.

Comment: If your main concern is actually that the receiver claims that they have not gotten the funds, you should read: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/93149/5406

Comment: I've closed it as a duplicate of the latter, since I think that is the primary concern that we can address here. We can't really explain the motivation for some UX considerations of some commercial service.